# Symfony2 updating the values and displaying them without refresh with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

first of all I want to say that im not an expert in front-end, and this is my first time digging in to ajax. So this is what I want to do:

I want to change and show the updated value without the full pages refresh.. The only thing I want to update is the input field with its values and thats it. How can I update only that portion of the code?

This is my twig(when i press the + button i increase the quantity of the product and i want the twig to update it without refreshing the whole page. Like in any standard shopping cart):

```
{% for key, item in cart %}
    {% if key == info.id %}
        <div class="input-append">
            <input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" value="{{ item }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="{{ key }}"/>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove btn"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>      
    {% endif %}         
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add/quantity',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            document.location.reload(true);
           }
        }
    });
});   
});
```

currently I only have the `document.location.reload(true);` which reloads the full page, how can I change that code?

The action :

```
public function addQuantityAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];
    /** logic*/
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $qtyAvailable = $qtyAvailable - 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
         $session->set('cart', $cart);
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the new value in the response of add/quantity action and the put where you want on your page:

```
success: function (data) {      
      if(data.success == false){
       alert('error')
      }else{
        // Assuming the value on data.amount
        $('.input-data input[type=text]').val(data.amount);
       }
    }
```

If you want, show me your action code (add/quantity) and helps there too.

I hope it helps

**UPDATE:**

In your action response:

```
$response->setData(array(
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Qunatity increased',
    'amount'  => $cart[ $productid ]
));
```

Comment: It wont change without refresh anyway... :(

Comment: Maybe this line is wrong: $('.input-data input[type=text]').val(data.amount); Its input-append, not input-data. In any case, you have the new value in the template, so you should can use it anywhere. The way depends of your DOM.

Comment: Hey I have a problem. The code you provided works, but it increases the value to all of the products, not just the one I pressed, and after refresh everything is fixed.. How can I make it so it only changes the input of the product i pressed the button on?

Comment: Change the selector to $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val(data.amount)

Comment: And one more question? Can I make the whole div change with the new data? something like this: $this.parent('.input-append').attr(data.amount) ?